# Search algorithm for unique result with multiple tags

Tags: c#, sql, search

I have three tables in sql server-

```
Photos table:

----------------------
| PhotoId | PhotoName|
----------------------
|         |          |
----------------------

Tags table:

----------------------
| TagId   |   TagName|
----------------------
|         |          |
----------------------

Junction table:

----------------------
| PhotoId |   TagId  |
----------------------
|         |          |
----------------------
```

A photo can have multiple tags, and a tag can belong to multiple photos.

Now, for example `Eagle` has tags `Bird, Animal, Wild`. I would like to search with tags `Domestic, Bird, Animal`. I'm using sql statement `where TagName='Domestic' OR TagName='Bird' OR TagName='Animal'`. The problem is, it produces query result where Eagle comes two times.

But I would like to have Eagle only once. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM photos p
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
               FROM junction j
               JOIN tags t ON t.TagId = j.TagId
               WHERE p.PhotoId = j.PhotoId
               AND t.TagName IN ('Domestic', 'Bird', 'Animal')
              )
```

Comment: With the right indexes, this is probably the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct p.*
from photos p
inner join Junction j on j.PhotoId = p.PhotoId
inner join tags t on j.TagId = t.TagId
where t.TagName in ('Domestic', 'Bird','Animal')
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest solution i can think of, you just only need to specify the name of the photo then do a distinct, then each Name of the animal will appear once based on the tag.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PhotoName
FROM Tags T
JOIN Junction J ON J.TagId = T.TagId
JOIN Photos P ON P.PhotoId = J.PhotoId
WHERE TagName=('Domestic' OR TagName='Bird') OR TagName='Animal'
```

Answer (score 1):

with DISTINCT each photo should appear only once in result set

```
select * from Photos
where PhotoId in
(   select DISTINCT PhotoId
    from Junction
    where TagId in
    (select TagId from Tags where TagName='Domestic' OR TagName='Bird' OR TagName='Animal')
)
```